# Eliminating multiple-extension file names from find output

Tags: find, filenames

I need to find the size of all files in `/etc` with the `.conf` extension. I tried to do this with `find /etc -type f -name "*.conf" -exec du -chB1 {} +`, but find gave me `.conf` files that have two or three extensions. The question is how can I filter `find` output in order to get just the files with **one** extension, that being `.conf` ? Can this be achieved through `find` or do I need another command ?

Comment: What do you mean by `two or three extensions`, can you clarify on that

Comment: How do you define an extension? What if the file name is `a.b.conf`. Where `a.b` is file name and `.conf` is an extension?

Comment: Well, for example I wanted to find file names like this one `/etc/pam.conf`, but instead the command above would give me something like this too `/etc.dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.bolt.conf`

Comment: What about a hidden `.ltrace.conf` file for instance?

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude the file names that contain more than one dot:

```
find /etc -type f  ! -name '*.*.*' -name '*.conf'
```

If you still want to print hidden `.conf` file names (if any, à la `/etc/.pwd.lock`) then

```
find /etc -type f ! -name '?*.*.*' -name '*.conf'
```

Comment: Suppose I am having a file with name `a.b.conf`. Where `a.b` is the name of the file and `.conf` is extension.

Comment: @Debian_yadav - according to you, according to the next guy the file name is `a` and `b` is another extension... you know, like `tar` in `tar.gz`...

Comment: One might prefer `! -name '?*.*.*'` to allow files named like `.socks.conf` for instance, where `.socks` can't possibly be considered as an _extension_ (it's rare to find such files in `/etc` except maybe in `/etc/skel` though).