# size of file bash

Tags: linux, scripting, find

i have to show size of all files .conf which are in /etc and redirect size output to a file.txt but i want to add to my command a flag which set a limit of redirected output

my command is:

```
find /etc -name "*.conf" -printf "%s\n" | paste -sd+ | bc > file.txt
```

but this command show 365077 bytes

and i want to have values between 120000 bytes and 300000 bytes of redirected output
that means when i cat file.txt to have a value between 120000bytes and 300000bytes

How to find the flag for command?

Comment: Why do you need the sum to be a certain size? Or do you only want to report when the total size is in that range?

Comment: I keep this on my toolbox `du -a | sort -n > file.txt`. `du` is faster than any other command, you can use it to list files/size

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes i want to report the total size is a range (120k -300k bytes)

Comment: @Jeff - sounds like a new [homework assignment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482023/22142) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict the result to sums between 120000 and 300000 bytes, then one way would be to add an `awk` filter at the end:

```
find ... | bc | awk '$1 >= 120000 && $1 <= 300000' > file.txt
```

This would create an empty `file.txt` for sums outside of the range, otherwise, the sum is sent to the file.

To create the file only if the sum is in the range:

```
... | awk '$1 >= 120000 && $1 <= 300000 { print $1 > "file.txt" }'
```

... to have awk write to the file; drop the redirection at the end.

Comment: this is working but also i want to have some value in file.txt but this value should be less then 300000 bytes and greater than 120000 bytes empty file is a problem can i do that?

Comment: @Max44, see the edit; I have awk write the file only if the sum is in the range.

Comment: this command doesn`t create the file.txt but i created with touch and after that i run entire command but when  type cat file.txt there nothing in

Comment: Well, if your result, as you showed in the question, was 365077, then that's outside the range, right?

Comment: yes, when i run cat file.txt it show 365077 but i want to show only between 120000 and 300000 bytes

Comment: Remove the file and try again; I can't reproduce that behavior.

Comment: find /etc -name "*.conf" -printf "%s\n" | paste -sd+ | bc | awk '$1 >= 120000 && $1 <= 300000 { print $1 > "file.txt" }'    this  command not create any file.txt i deleted the file and try again and still nothhing

Comment: perfect! You said you didn't want the file if the sum was outside the range!

Comment: maybe it was my mistake but i want to have some value in file.txt which is between 120000 bytes and 300000 bytes but is important to have value in the file.txt

Comment: u can make a shell script with 3 lines

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find /etc -name \*.conf 2> /dev/null | xargs du -sc | tail -n1
1092    total
```

Total size of `.conf` files on this host the user running this command has permission to inspect is 1092 bytes.

Comment: i want to redirect output to a specific file.txt and after that when i try cat file.txt to display values between 120k 300k bytes

Comment: That seems trivial enough.  Edit your question to show this, and what you have tried, and how it did not work as expected or intended.

Comment: i did it check description